# How to select row in wicket table

Tags: java, wicket

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [making entire row of a wicket datable clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796342/making-entire-row-of-a-wicket-datable-clickable)

I have table with player. Now I want to select one row with player and then push button to registered him. How I can select row in table ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look in [wicket example's repeater section](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples-6.0.x/repeater/). It shows most of the tables you can use in wicket and they all have a "select" action, which is a AbsractColumn with a custom panel in it.

```
...

 columns.add(new AbstractColumn<Contact, String>(new Model<String>("Actions"))
    {
        public void populateItem(Item<ICellPopulator<Contact>> cellItem, String componentId,
            IModel<Contact> model)
        {
            cellItem.add(new ActionPanel(componentId, model));
        }
    });

...

class ActionPanel extends Panel
{
    public ActionPanel(String id, IModel<Contact> model)
    {
        super(id, model);
        add(new Link("select")
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick()
            {
                selected = (Contact)getParent().getDefaultModelObject();
            }
        });
    }
}

public Contact getSelected()
{
    return selected;
}

public void setSelected(Contact selected)
{
    addStateChange();
    this.selected = selected;
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: yes this works but only if I push to the link. I want to select player when I select row

Comment: Check this question. It does exactly what you want : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796342/making-entire-row-of-a-wicket-datable-clickable