# How to make the entire row of a ListView clickable in wicket

Tags: wicket-1.6

Is it possible to make the entire row of a **ListView** clickable in wicket?I've seen this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796342/making-entire-row-of-a-wicket-datable-clickable),
But i need a scrollable table instead of pagination. Thats why i am going for a **ListView** where upon clicking any row of the table, content of the row should be displayed below the table for editing.

thanks,

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

is essentially the same way, you have to pass a model to the list view...

```
//in ListView class
protected void populateItem(final ListItem<T> item) {

    item.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("onclick") {
    @Override
    protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                T object=item.getModelObject();     
                //do some stuff or a callback, besides you can use ajax 
    }
    });

}
```